# Obter tamanho de uma matriz bidimensional

Tags: c, array, struct

Tenho uma matriz bidimensonal de char dinamicamente alocada, como faco para obter seu tamanho?

usaria sizeof(cliente);

por exemplo, instanciei uma struct Cliente, 
Cliente **cliente; depois no codigo vou alocando ela a medida que vai (tamVetor ++ e realloc); recebendo dados na sua estrutura:

int tamVetor = 0;
exemplo: cliente = realloc(sizeof(char*)*tamVetor);
                  cliente[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*150);

Dentro da função que este codigo esta implementado consigo imprimir os x indices da struct atraves de um for aonde, for(int i = 0; i < tamVetor; i++);

Porem, essa funcao retorna a struct pra outra função que a chamou, exemplo:

char **result = (funcao que recebe de retorno a struct);

Nessa funcao agora quero printar os campos das structs, porem fazendo sizeof(result); sempre da um valor muito baixo que nao sei dando veio .

E por exemplo, se eu sei que tenho 12 clientes da minha struct, e nessa funcao, na hora de printar os campos da struct na tela coloco for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) printa corretamente, mas se coloco for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(result); i++); printa apenas alguns clientes, mas nao da erro nenhum.

Comment: `sizeof()` é calculado em *tempo de compilação*. Ele não ajuda em nada para se calcular o tamanho de um bloco de memória alocado em *tempo de execução*.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível se determinar quanta memória foi alocada a partir apenas do ponteiro.

`sizeof(p)` não é capaz de determinar em tempo de execução o tamanho do bloco de memória que foi alocado anteriormente. `sizeof(p)` retorna o tamanho da variável de ponteiro `p`, que por sua vez, é calculado em tempo de compilação.

`p` armazena somente endereço inicial do bloco de memória que foi alocado.

Sempre que você aloca um bloco de memória, `malloc()` retorna o endereço inicial desse bloco, mas o fim do bloco não poderá ser determinado a partir dele, já que não há nenhum tipo terminador para delimitar o fim desse bloco.

Você é quem deve *saber* onde é o fim do bloco, portanto, você deve armazenar o comprimento do bloco em algum lugar para *lembrar* o seu tamanho exato.

Por outro lado, você pode implementar um mecanismo capaz de reter o tamanho do bloco alocado juntamente com seu respectivo ponteiro, por exemplo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct pointer_s
{
    size_t size;
    void * p;
};

typedef struct pointer_s pointer_t;

pointer_t * my_malloc( size_t s )
{
    pointer_t * ptr = malloc(sizeof(pointer_t));
    ptr->p = malloc(s);
    ptr->size = s;
    return ptr;
}

void my_free( pointer_t * ptr )
{
    free(ptr->p);
    free(ptr);
}

int main( void )
{
    pointer_t * p = my_malloc( 123 );

    printf( "%ld\n", p->size );

    my_free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oi Lacobus, so esclarecendo que sou iniciante em programação, e alguns conceitos são a primeira vez que vejo, e ainda não dominei completamente o assunto de ponteiro. Não entendi o exemplo generico que me passou, nao entendi como eu implementaria no meu codigo se tiver outro, ou algum materia pra ler especificamente sobre isso fico agradecido.